# Angle between two vectors equipped with special inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u\neq0 $ and $v\neq 0$ be two vectors in a vector space with inner product such as $\left \| u \right \|=\left \| v \right \|=\left \| u-v \right \|$. Determine the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Progress:

$\cos\theta=\frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \| u \right \|\left \| v \right \|}=\frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \| u-v \right \|^2}=\frac{\left \| u-v \right \|^2-2\left \| u \right \|^2}{2\left \| u \right \|^2}=\frac{-\left \| u \right \|^2}{2 \left \| u \right \|^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$

$\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow \theta=\frac{2\pi }{3}$. Correct answer is $\theta=\frac{\pi }{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\|u-v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2-2(u\cdot v)$$ implies that

$$
\|v\|^2=2(u\cdot v)
$$

and then simplify and reorganize this

$$
\frac{\|v\|^2}{\|u\|\|v\|}=\frac{2(u\cdot v)}{\|u\|\|v\|}
$$
 to get the correct value of $1/2$.

---

The problem in your computation seems to be after the second equality:

$$
\|u-v\|^2-2\|v\|^2=-2(u\cdot v)
$$

but not $2(u\cdot v)$ as you wanted.

You would be on the right track to use

$$2\|v\|^2-\|u-v\|^2$$

and then the sign error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Your third equality is wrong. Instead of $\frac{||u-v^2||^2-2||u||^2}{2||u||^2}$, it should read $\frac{2||u||^2-||u-v^2||^2}{2||u||^2}$, which yields the right answer.